# When rep is displayed on Stack Overflow Careers it should contain commas for readability

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

Consider [Nicholas Larsen](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/nicklarsen), his is the sample profile you get from the [main Careers page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/).

His rep is listed as 10527 without any commas to make it more readable.

[image: Section from Nicholas Larsen's page]

Constrast that with his [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/178082/nick-larsen) where the number is displayed as 10,527.

Comment: Even better it should say 11k - these extra digits contain very little useful information.

Comment: For the record, that's called digit grouping..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just went out to prod but might be not immediately refresh due to caching so give it up to a day...

Thanks for the report :)